# problem with my page transitions in CSS/jS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

so when doing these page transitions I can have one work but when i try to call out two transitions only one works. what am i doing wrong? tried some different stuff I'm stuck.

In my JavaScript I have it called out just to grab all .transitions so I should be able to do -1 or -name after them to call out multipole right? it works fine if I do one page transition per page but once i start adding more then one to one set page html it only animates one.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const transition_el = document.querySelector('.transition');
    const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');

    setTimeout( () => {
        transition_el.classList.remove('is-active');

    }, 500);

    for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        const anchor = anchors[i];

        anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let target = e.target.href;

            transition_el.classList.add('is-active');

            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href = target;

            }, 500)
        });

    }
}
```

```css
/*catching*/

.transition-catching {
    content: url(/HP/Catching.svg);
    position:absolute; 
    width: 27%; 
    margin-top:19.3%; 
    margin-left:20%;
    z-index: 101;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.transition-catching.is-active {
    margin-left: -500px;
}

/*clean*/

.transition-clean {
    content: url(/HPA/Clean.svg);
    position:absolute; 
    width: 81%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: -20%;
    z-index: 101;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.transition-clean.is-active {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div>

      <a href="contact.html" class="transition transition-catching is-active"></a>

      <a href="contact.html" class="transition transition-clean is-active"></a>  
      
    </div>

  </body>
```

```html
  <body>
    <div>

      <a href="contact.html" class="transition transition-catching is-active"></a>

      <a href="contact.html" class="transition transition-clean is-active"></a>
      
    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: transition_el is the first element on the page with class of transition.  Instead of adding the is active class to transition_el, try adding it to e.target.

Comment: Are you talking about within my JavaScript? so i add the is active class to e.target? where in the JavaScript would  do that? just confused on how I would write that. sorry new to JavaScript only started learning this month